# (Python3) Conditional Mean in Garch Model

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, mean, volatility

I am using "arch" package of python . I am fitting a GARCH(1,1) model with mean model ARX. After the fitting, we can call the conditional volatility directly. However, I don't know how to call the modeled conditional mean values

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the attribute `resid` you can compute fitted values.  For example

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
st = dt.datetime(1990,1,1)
en = dt.datetime(2016,1,1)
data = web.get_data_yahoo('^GSPC', start=st, end=en)
returns = 100 * data['Adj Close'].pct_change().dropna()

from arch import arch_model
am = arch_model(returns, mean='AR',lags=1)
res = am.fit(update_freq=5)
fitted = returns - res.resid
fitted.plot()
```